# Why Can't Python Recognize Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I tried to import the BeautifulSoup library using the following code:

`from beautifulsoup4 import beautifulsoup4`

I got the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/123wa/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/web-scrape.py", line 2, in <module>
    from beautifulsoup4 import beautifulsoup4
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beautifulsoup4'
```

I used pip list and confirmed the module is named beautifulsoup4. What is the proper way to import the BeautifulSoup library?

Comment: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` that's how `BeautifulSoup` imported

Answer (score 0):

The error is arising because of the way the library is being loaded. The correct way to import BeautifulSoup is

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

See the Quick Start guide at: https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/